# CSS Custom Dropdown Select that works across all browsers IE7+ FF Webkit

Tags: css, cross-browser

I would like to make a custom dropdown that works across all the browsers. I created one here but the arrow is not clickable. If I set it as the background for the select, then firefox will overwrite an arrow on top of it. Can someone tell me what's the best technique to get a custom looking dropdown that works across all the browsers and how do I make that knob clickable without Javascript?

http://jsfiddle.net/DJDf8/1/

CSS:

```css
#menulist {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  height: 32px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 260px;
  text-indent: 8px;
}

.arrow {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 32px;
  width: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: #c8c8c8;
  background: url('http://icons.aniboom.com/Energy/Resources/userControls/TimeFrameDropDownFilter/Dropdown_Arrow.png') 0;
}
```

```html
<span style="position:relative;">
         <span class="arrow" ></span>
<select id="menulist">
         <option value="one">One</option>
         <option value="two">Two</option>
</select>
</span>
```

Comment: I wouldn't worry so much [about ie7](http://theie7countdown.com/) and would worry more [about ie6](http://www.ie6countdown.com/).

Answer (score 23):

This is very simple, you just need to add a background image to the select element and position it where you need to, but don't forget to add:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
```

According to http://shouldiprefix.com/#appearance

Microsoft Edge and IE mobile support this property with the -webkit- prefix rather than -ms- for interop reasons.

I just made this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/drjorgepolanco/uxxvayqe/

Comment: Did you try ```-ms-appearance: none;```?

Answer (score 9):

As per Link: http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/ there are lot of extra rework that needs to be done(Put extra div and position the image there. Also the design will break as the option drilldown will be mis alligned to the the select.

Here is an easy and simple way which will allow you to put your own dropdown image and remove the browser default dropdown.(Without using any extra div). Its cross browser as well.

HTML

```
<select class="dropdown" name="drop-down">
  <option value="select-option">Please select...</option>
  <option value="Local-Community-Enquiry">Option 1</option>
  <option value="Bag-Packing-in-Store">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

CSS

```
select.dropdown {
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  height: 48px;
  width: 100%;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #666666;
  padding: 9px;
  font-family: tescoregular;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #666666;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background: url('yoururl/dropdown.png') no-repeat 97% 50% #ffffff;
  background-size: 11px 7px;
}
```

Comment: I like this solution. The only relevant part in the CSS are appearance and background.

Answer (score 8):

You might check **Select2** plugin:

http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Select2 is a jQuery based replacement for select boxes. It supports searching, remote data sets, and infinite scrolling of results.

It's quite popular and very maintainable.
It should cover most of your needs if not all.

Comment: Nice, but the question was for a CSS solution with no JS

Answer (score 2):

The `pointer-events` could be useful for this problem as you would be able to put a div over the arrow button, but still be able to click the arrow button.

The `pointer-events` css makes it possible to click through a div.

This approach will not work for IE versions older than IE11, however. You could something working in IE8 and IE9 if the element you put on top of the arrow button is an `SVG` element, but it will be more complicated to style the button the way you want proceeding like this.

Here a Js fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/e7qnqzx6/2/

Answer (score 1):

I was also having a similar problem. Finally found one solution at https://techmeals.com/fe/questions/htmlcss/4/How-to-customize-the-select-drop-down-in-css-which-works-for-all-the-browsers

Note:

1) For Firefox support there is special CSS handling for SELECT element's parent, please take a closer look.

2) Download the down.png from [Down.png](https://techmeals.com/external/images/down.png)

**CSS code**

```
        /* For Firefox browser we need to style for SELECT element parent. */

        @-moz-document url-prefix() {

            /* Please note this is the parent of "SELECT" element */

            .select-example {   
                background: url('https://techmeals.com/external/images/down.png');
                background-color: #FFFFFF;
                border: 1px solid #9e9e9e;
                background-size: auto 6px;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: 96% 13px;
            }
        }

        /* IE specific styles */
        @media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) 
        {
                select.my-select-box {
                padding: 0 0 0 5px;
            }
        }

        /* IE specific styles */
        @supports (-ms-accelerator:true) {
                select.my-select-box {
                padding: 0 0 0 5px;
            }
        }

        select.my-select-box  {
            outline: none;
            background: #fff;
            -moz-appearance: window;
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            border-radius: 0px;
            text-overflow: "";
            background-image: url('https://techmeals.com/external/images/down.png');
            background-size: auto 6px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: 96% 13px;
            cursor: pointer;
            height: 30px;
            width: 100%;
            border: 1px solid #9e9e9e;
            padding: 0 15px 0 5px;
            padding-right: 15px\9;      /* This will be apllied only to IE 7, IE 8 and IE 9 as */
            *padding-right: 15px;        /* This will be apllied only to IE 7 and below. */
            _padding-right: 15px;       /* This will be apllied only to IE 6 and below. */
        }
```

**HTML code**

```
    <div class="select-example">
        <select class="my-select-box">
            <option value="1">First Option</option>
            <option value="2">Second Option</option>
            <option value="3">Third Option</option>
            <option value="4">Fourth Option</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```html
<select class="dropdownmenu" name="drop-down">
    <option class="dropdownmenu_list1" value="select-option">Choose ...</option>
    <option class="dropdownmenu_list2" value="Topic 1">Option 1</option>
    <option class="dropdownmenu_list3" value="Topic 2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

This works best in Firefox. Too bad that Chrome and Safari do not support this rather easy CSS styling.