# IE dropdown issue

Tags: css

If click on select dropdown and choose any last item in IE, again you select any item drop down will go to up not down but we need to fix if click on dropdown button it will come down all item.
As like chrome and firefox.
Example:
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdsa/2ZUNZ/)

```
<select  class="dropDown">
    <option>mango</option>
    <option>banana</option>
    <option>pomegranate</option>
    <option>papaya</option>
    <option>mango</option>
    <option>banana</option>
    <option>pomegranate</option>
    <option>papaya</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The issue is in IE10 right?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the new behavior of the `select` element in IE10. As far as I know you cannot change it. It's up to the browser to choose how the select element should look. You can however create your own custom dropdown using javascript and css. There are many resources on this on stackoverflow.

Here's a few:

- [CSS Custom Dropdown Select that works across all browsers IE7+ FF Webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18092123/css-custom-dropdown-select-that-works-across-all-browsers-ie7-ff-webkit)
- [Custom dropdown box using javascript and css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834380/custom-dropdown-box-using-javascript-and-css)

You should ask yourself if it's really neccessary to fix this "issue", as IE10 users would likely be used to this behavior.