# color the background of a combobox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, view, combobox

I want to color my combo boxes to have a grey background when it is inactive (meaning even before the user clicks on it).  Here is an example of what I want:

[image]

This is the css that I have tried:

```
select option {
    margin:40px;
    background-color: #ddd1d1;
    color: #000;
    text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
```

However, that css only colors the combobox when opened. Now I want to be able to color it before the user even touches it.

Comment: Working Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/hrxfnd2a/

Comment: @ramiramilu, thank you. Is there a way to change the arrow style to be similar to above as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try applying the css to just the combobox:

```
      select{
        margin:40px;
        background-color: #ddd1d1;
        color: #000;
        text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
      }
```

The css you provided only applies the styling to the options (or items) inside the combobox, so when you open the combobox it the style is then applied. The css provided above applies the style to all options in the combobox.

Here's some CSS that does what you're looking for. It utilizes CSS3 attribute selection.

```
    select[disabled]{
        margin:40px;
        background-color: #ddd1d1;
        color: #000;
        text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    }
```

#### Update

Per comment, here's what I've found for drop down arrows:

The only way I could get it to work, was to add a `DIV` and a new css class as per answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18092123/css-custom-dropdown-select-that-works-across-all-browsers-ie7-ff-webkit). Basically, you're "hiding" the `SELECT` without disabling it (this is where you get creative with your CSS across browsers). Maintain the same sizes between both `SELECT` and `DIV` and give the `DIV` all of the styling. Example:

```
    <style>
      .selector{
        width: 200px;
        height: 34px;
        background: url(new_arrow.png) no-repeat right #ddd1d1;
        color: #000;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
      }
      .selector select{
        background: transparent;
        width: 200px;
        height: 34px;
        /* for major browsers */
        appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
      }
      select option{
        background-color: #ddd1d1;
        color: #000;
        height: 34px;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
      }
    </style>
    <div class="selector">
      <select>
        <option>Test1</option>
        <option>Test2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: tbm0115, that works great.  Now is there a way to change the arrow style?

Comment: You could check out this question for arrow styles. It get's a bit more complicated with components of a control. You usually have to provide images for each component. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18092123/css-custom-dropdown-select-that-works-across-all-browsers-ie7-ff-webkit